# How to make my Google Scholar account searchable?

Tags: google-scholar

I recently created my Google scholar account. I linked my account to my school email address and my papers. I also made the profile public. However, my profile is still not searchable by others.

I would like to create a hyperlink for my name in some way. For example, if you search Richard Feynman on Google scholar, his name has a hyperlink and we can access his other papers from it.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8JPu.png)

Does anyone know how to set up this hyperlink? Is it only allowed to a famous author or research with tons of publications?

Comment: Can you post your google scholar link/ name? It would help with people trying to run test-cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go Moss, from Google's FAQ found [Here](https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/citations.html#setup):

--
Making Site Public:
--

```
Click the "Edit" button next to your name, check the "Make my profile public" box, and 
click "Save".

If the "Edit" button doesn't appear, sign in to the Google account that you used to 
create your profile.
```

--
Sharing Link:
--

```
You can share the URL displayed by the browser. It looks like this:

https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=ID&hl=en

…where ID identifies your Google Scholar profile. You can link to it from your 
homepage, email it to colleagues, or share it on social media. The link only works if 
the profile is public, and only lets other people see the profile but not make changes 
to it.
```

Comment: @Moss as a follow up to that, you could store the link in a plain text format that has a link using , for example, hyperlinks \[ Text you want \] \( Link to your profile \)